# Error - ForbiddenAttributesError Ruby on Rails 4 Passing through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a .NET developer and currently working on ROR. As a started facing few difficulties. I hope you can help me.

A ruby webapi put request is made for updating participant data in MongoDB. I am facing issue

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)
```

When searched on google it suggest that some attributes are not passed and need to check Model

Below is my model

```
class ParticipantSession
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :participant
  embeds_many :participant_activity_records

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant_activity_records
  alias_method :activity_records=, :participant_activity_records_attributes=

  field :emergency_count, type: Integer
  field :sb0_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb1_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb2_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb3_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb4_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb5_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb6_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb7_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb8_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :sb10_cumulative_time, type: String
  field :login, type: DateTime 

  def ordered_activities
    participant_activity_records.sort_by(&:id)
  end

  def render renderer
    renderer.render_participant_session(self)
  end
end
```

This is how data is passed to participant_session

```
participant.participant_sessions.new(participant_data['activity_records'])
```

Data that is passed in cumulative_time is as below

```
{"activity_records":{
"sb0_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb1_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb2_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb3_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb4_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb5_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb6_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb7_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb8_cumulative_time":"0",
"sb10_cumulative_time":"0",
"emergency_count":5,
"login":"2016-02-33 19:40:12"
}
}
```

Please help in resolving the error

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError)
```

API Controller Code

```
class Api::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  before_filter :protect_with_api_key

  def update
    status = true
    participant_ids = []
    unless params[:participants].blank?
      params[:participants].each do |participant_data|
        participant = Participant.where(participant_id: participant_data['participant_id']).first
        unless participant.present?
          status = false
          participant_ids << participant_data['participant_id']
        else
          activity_records = participant_data['cumulative_time']['activity_records']
          participant_data['cumulative_time']['activity_records'] = [] if activity_records.nil?
          participant.participant_sessions.new(participant_data['cumulative_time'])
          participant.save!
        end
      end
    end 

    if status
      render :json => {status: "OK"}
    else
      render :json => {error: "No participant with id #{participant_ids.join(',')}"}, :status => 422
    end 
  end
  end
```

Data Passed

I am passing following data to API

```
{"participants":[
{"logout":"1970-01-01 05:30:00","login":"2016-02-33 19:40:12","cumulative_time":{"activity_records":[],"sb0_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb1_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb2_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb3_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb4_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb5_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb6_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb7_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb8_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "sb10_cumulative_time": "00h 00m 00s",
            "emergency_count": 0},"emergency_count":5, "participant_id":22}
]}
```

RAILS version 4 is used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to permit parameter before assigning to your ActiveModel.

Here is example of how to permit data

```
params.require(:activity_records).permit!
```

Please refer detail information of usage on official documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ForbiddenAttributesError.html

Comment: Sorry error is not resolved. It is still throwing the same error. I am looking into documentation links you had provided and if resolved will surely accept this answer.

Comment: if you gist your controller code, I can help to solve it.

Comment: I have edited my question. You can check code for api controller there.

Comment: Great, can you please add code of method `participant_data` ?

Comment: participant_data is not a method I think. It's part of each loop I think.

Please check updated question for set of data I am passing